# Plone buildout error non-existant file

Tags: plone, buildout

I have a Plone 4.3.3 site that is throwing an error on buildout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Proforest4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.5-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1946, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/usr/local/Proforest4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.5-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 626, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/usr/local/Proforest4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.5-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1370, in _call
    return f()
  File "/data/usr/local/Proforest4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.precompiler-0.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/precompiler/__init__.py", line 29, in install
    return self._run()
  File "/data/usr/local/Proforest4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.precompiler-0.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/precompiler/__init__.py", line 35, in _run
    self._compile_eggs()
  File "/data/usr/local/Proforest4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.precompiler-0.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/precompiler/__init__.py", line 67, in _compile_eggs
    py_compile.compile(fn, None, None, True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/py_compile.py", line 123, in compile
    with open(cfile, 'wb') as fc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/usr/local/Proforest4.3/test/src/proforest.content/proforest/content/behaviours/accordion.pyc'
```

accordion.py does exist, but not the .pyc version

Permissions on accordion.py seem correct (owned by plone_buildout etc.)

How do I resolve?

Answer (score 3):

You user is trying to *create* that file, but filesystem permissions are wrong.

Check that the Plone effective-user is able to write in buildout folders.

Comment: If you've used the Unified Installer, and installed as root, you probably need to run buildout as the plone_buildout user:

sudo -u plone_buildout bin/buildout

Using a separate user to run buildout allows us to keep the daemon user from writing into the code directories.